# Testing Morris.js graphs with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, morris.js

I use [Morris.js](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/) for graphs in ruby on rails and find it very useful. However, I am not sure how to test the graphs using feature specs in rspec with capybara. At the very least I would like to test the following

- the graph is displaying on the page
- the right type of graph e.g. a line graph
- there is some data being plotted, e.g. check there are two lines in the graph.

How do you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can now answer the first two parts of the question. If the graph is working, the javascript code inserts an html svg element in the page. So using a feature spec with `js: true`, you can test for this with:

`page.should have_css 'svg'`

If you have different graphs on the same page, you can wrap each in a `div` and test with something like:

    `within :css, 'div#first_chart' do
        page.should have_css 'svg'
    end`

This does not exactly tell you that you have the right type of Morris graph in there, but should suffice for most purposes.

I still do not know how to check more detailed features like the number of lines appearing on a graph.